# What is the function of the stepControl property on mat-step directives?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

On the Angular Material stepper there is a `stepControl` property on each `mat-step` that contains a form.  What does the `stepControl` property do?

```
<mat-step [stepControl]="registrationForm">
```

It seems like the function would be to disallow moving to the next step if the form is not valid, but just wanted to double check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct, however, if any form validation is not compulsory you can use the `isOptional` property to ignore that form's validity and proceed to the next step.

```js
<mat-step [stepControl]="registrationForm" [optional]="isOptional">
```

Similarly if you are not using Reactive Forms you can use another property called `completed` to allow the user to proceed to the next step only if completed is true

```js
<mat-step [completed]="isCompleted">
```

Comment: Awesome answer - Thanks!